Need to call an async instance method from a sync instance method
send_message() gets called from a thread. Since my_channel.send() is async, I think it is necessary to have a synchronous send_message() call the asynchronous asend_message(). How can it be done?
#@typechecked
class MessageCog(Cog):

    @typechecked
    async def asend_message(self, message:str)->str:
        my_channel:TextChannel    = self.bot.get_channel(self.channel)
        assert isinstance(my_channel, TextChannel)
        embed     :Embed          = Embed(title="Response", description=message, color=pepe_green)
        assert isinstance(embed, Embed)
        my_message:Message        = await my_channel.send(embed=embed)
        assert isinstance(my_message, Message)
        result    :str            = str(my_message) # ??
        assert isinstance(result, str)
        if not isinstance(result, str): raise Exception()
        return result

    @typechecked
    def send_message(self, message:str)->str:
        #
        #f:Coroutine = lambda m: self.asend_message(m)
        #result:str = run(f)
        #
        #result:str = run(self.asend_message(message))
        #
        #result:str = get_running_loop().run_untilcomplete(self.asend_message(message))
        #
        #f:Callable[[str],str] = async_to_sync(MessageCog.asend_message)
        #
        #f = async_to_sync(MessageCog.asend_message)
        #result:str = f(self, message)
        #
        #result:str = create_task(self.asend_message(message))
        #
        #f = partial(MessageCog.asend_message, self)
        #result:str = run(f(message))
        assert isinstance(result, str)
        if not isinstance(result, str): raise Exception()
        return result

Errors are always the same:
[chain/error] [chain:AgentExecutor] [82.96s] Chain run errored with error:
...
TypeError: type of the return value must be str; got coroutine instead

UPDATE: new errors!
I think I finally got the types right. async returns a Coroutine that returns a str.
async def asend_message(self, message:str)->Coroutine[str]:

lambda creates a callable that returns a coroutine that...
f:Callable[[str],Coroutine[str]] = lambda m: self.asend_message(m)
g:Coroutine[str] = f(message)
result:str = run(g)

Upon seeing the new error, my initial reaction was to blame langchain, but I think the stack trace indicates a problem with how I'm using asyncio:
[tool/error] [chain:AgentExecutor > tool:send_message] [3ms] Tool run errored with error:
RuntimeError('Timeout context manager should be used inside a task')Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_core/tools.py", line 409, in run
    context.run(

  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain_core/tools.py", line 750, in _run
    else self.func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/user/enumerate_bot/./eris.py", line 380, in <lambda>
    func       =lambda message: self. send_message(message),

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/typeguard.py", line 494, in wrapper
    retval = func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/user/enumerate_bot/./eris.py", line 335, in send_message
    result:str = run(g)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()

  File "/home/user/enumerate_bot/./eris.py", line 306, in asend_message
    my_message:Message        = await my_channel.send(embed=embed)

  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 1618, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, params=params)

  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 638, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as response:

  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1197, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro

  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 507, in _request
    with timer:

  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 715, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError(

RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task


Take a look at asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe
